# Would a question about editors for MediaWiki code be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to add a question about which fully-functioning editors exist for MediaWiki (i.e., it colour-codes each components of the code, e.g., text within `<ref>` `</ref>` tags would say be highlighted with a grey background. Likewise templates (i.e., that between `{{` and `}}` braces)) but I'm afraid it'll be labelled as off-topic and I'd be barred from asking further questions on this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - item 4 in the "not on topic" part

Answer (score 0):

A question to get a list of resources would indeed, as you suspected, be off topic, as per [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.